# Pretty url doesn't show in url-bar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess file with several redirects, Now I want to create a pretty url for some link. I tried the following sentence and it does nothing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/example1.html /?page_id=100 [NC]
```

When I type www.MyDomain.com/?page_id=100 in my browser, the site shows, but the url still looks the same as I typed it. How would I change my sentence to show example.html in the url-bar instead of ?page_id=100 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what to do? I was clearly directed to RewriteRule by several site to create pretty urls. The problem is the url changes to the ugly one in the URL-bar. I want it to stay pretty when the actual site is being accessed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a rule that says:

When the browser requests: **`/example1.html`**

Then show them: **`/?page_id=100`**

It goes one way, it doesn't do anything if the browser requests **`/?page_id=100`**. If you want to do something about a browser requesting the query string URL, *you need a rule to tell mod_rewrite to do it*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index\.php)?\?page_id=100($|\ |&)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /example1.html?%3 [L,R=301]
```

Also, you may want to get rid of the `/` in the pattern of your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^example1.html /?page_id=100 [NC]
```

Leading slashes are stripped off when matching against rules in an htaccess file.